# SBT : automatic generation of allOutputFiles

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT version 1.3.13 - According to [SBT documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Track-File-Inputs-and-Outputs.html#File+outputs):

> Like allInputFiles, there is an allOutputFiles task of return type Seq[Path] that is automatically generated for a task, foo, if the return type of foo is one of Seq[Path], Path, Seq[File] or File.

This seems to work with Seq[Path] and Path as expected:

```
val outputTask = Def.taskKey[Seq[java.nio.file.Path]]("")
outputTask := Seq[java.nio.file.Path]()
val printOutputs = Def.taskKey[Unit]("")
printOutputs := println((outputTask / allOutputFiles).value)    // result: Vector()
```

However, if I change `java.nio.file.Path`s to `java.io.File`s it fails on loading:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   outputTask / allOutputFiles from printOutputs
```

I'm looking into the [SBT source code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.3.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/nio/Settings.scala#L40) but I haven't got a clue yet. Any insight on why it works with `Path` `Seq[Path]` but not with `File` `Seq[File]`?